# Can I configure gcc to always output to the code file's name instead of a.exe?

Tags: gcc, g++

By default, when running `gcc test.c`, gcc will output the executable as `a.exe`. Is there a way to globally override this so that gcc will create `test.exe`?

This assumes that there's only one input file - otherwise gcc can choose to use a.exe, or perhaps to use the first file's name.

Comment: That's usually done with makefile rules.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I want it to be system wide, not project specific.

Comment: Other than using `make` (with or without a Makefile) as mentioned by @ThomasDickey, the obvious answer is to use `gcc`'s `-o` option:  `gcc test.c -o test.exe`.  Using `make` is a much better choice, though.

Comment: If you were using a Unix system, then you would write a simple shell wrapper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's usually done with makefile rules, e.g., given `test.c`, you would be able to do this (even *without* having a makefile):

```
make test
```

Likewise, there are predefined rules for g++, given `test2.cc`, you could do the same thing:

```
make test2
```

But in either case, you probably need libraries.  Doing that is what makefiles are good for (in addition to providing ways of compiling multiple objects).

gcc by itself doesn't have an option to simulate makefile rules.  If you want a tool which does that, you could make a shell script which does the special case mentioned, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in "$@"
do
    case "$name" in
    *.c)
        gcc -o $(basename "$name") "$name"
        ;;
    *.cc)
        g++ -o $(basename "$name") "$name"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "ignoring $name, since it is not one of my files!"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

But (see the beginning of the answer), the script merely makes explicit the feature that the predefined rules for `make` provide you.  On the other hand, you *could* modify the script to add necessary libraries, and do that in one place (rather than a set of makefiles, which seems to be the issue).

By the way: whether gcc automatically provides a ".exe" suffix (when you do not) depends upon the platform and the compiler configuration.  The suffix is not useful on Unix-like platforms and is generally optional on related things such as Cygwin.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but as I mentioned in my comment, makefiles aren't a solution for what I'm looking for - I want a system wide solutions and yours is project specific (i.e. I have to define a separate makefile for each project).

Comment: @Mark no you don't. There are default rules for `make`. If you have a file `widget.c` then try `make widget`. You can even specify the default set of libraries to be included in the link stage by specifying them in the environment variable `LDLIBS` (e.g. `export LDLIBS='-lm -lterminfo'`)

Comment: Some other tools, e.g. `dkms`, depend on standard `make` behavior.  If you change `make` "system wide", you'll break things.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a way to make gcc to create a binary file and use the name of the .c file compiled from by default.
However here is a quick bash script I created, I run this instead of gcc:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=${1##*/}; output=${temp%.c}
gcc $1 -o $output $2
```

Unrelated, I expanded the script to compile with the name by default, and execute that binary if the file exists. I am sure this can be adjusted better as if a file with said name exists it will always run, but it suites my purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=${1##*/}; output=${temp%.c}

gcc $1 -o $output $2

if [ -f $output ]; then
    echo "==== $output being run ===="
    ./$output
fi
```

Comment: Instead of running 4(!) programs, in bash/ksh/zsh you can do `temp=${1##*/}; output=${temp%??}` or safer `... ${temp%.c}`. In any shell since about 7th-ed (1980) you can use `$(basename $1 .c)`.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085! I updated my post, also added "$2" at the end of the gcc statement if you need to include other parameters (Like `-ld` when working with math.h).